# distance/magnitude between quaternions, but ignore roll

Tags: javascript, math, quaternions, gl-matrix

I'm searching for a way to determine if a camera (`a`) is looking at the same direction than a specific object (`b`).

I'm only working with the rotations because here we don't care about the positions (so we can consider both are located at the origin).

I'm working with quaternions, using gl-matrix.

After many searches and tests, I understood that I can determine the "distance" (magnitude ?) between the two quaternions using a dot product.

```
var a = quat.create();
quat.rotateY(a, a, Math.PI);

var b = quat.create();
quat.rotateY(b, b, Math.PI);

quat.dot(a, b)
```

That works well in many cases (it returns a number in range [0..1] : from `1` if both are exactly looking at the same direction to `0` if both are totally opposite).

However, in my case, I don't want to care about the "roll" between the objects. I mean that the camera (`a`) can be turned upside down, relatively to (`b`), but still looking at the same point.

For example, if I turn `b` by 180 degrees around Z, I get a dot product that is around `0`, while it's still looking at the same direction.

```
var a = quat.create();
quat.rotateY(a, a, Math.PI);

var b = quat.create();
quat.rotateY(b, b, Math.PI);
quat.rotateZ(b, b, Math.PI);

quat.dot(a, b);
```

I tried many things, such as multiplying the inverse of `a` with `b`, or `[s]lerp`, but I still can't get anything that fits my requirements.

Of course, I can't simply separate and work with the absolute Z axis, because everything is all relative here, so the roll could be around any axis.

How can I get that result ?

EDIT : Thanks to LutzL answer, here's how I implemented the solution :

```
var r = quat.create();
quat.invert(r, a);
quat.multiply(r, r, b);

var distance = r[3]*r[3] - r[0]*r[0] - r[1]*r[1] + r[2]*r[2];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpret it the way that the unit vector of the Z axis (in local coordinates) is your forward pointing vector?

The quaternion a describes the translation of the local coordinate frame to the global coordinate frame. Thus a vector v in local coordinates has direction a*v*a' (a'=conjugate of a=inverse for unit quaternion) in the global frame. The direction of the Z axis thus changes according to ka=a*k*a'.

The Z direction of the second object is thus kb=b*k*b'. The cosine of the angle between them is the scalar product of ka and kb which is also the real part of ka'*kb=a*k'*a'*b*k*b'. The real part of any quaternion v remains unchanged in a'*v*a, so

> scal(ka,kb) = real( ka * kb' )
>
> = -real( k * a' * b * k * b' * a ) = -real( k * (a' * b) * k * (a'* b)' )

I do not know the specifics of the GL implementation, but the operations are to compute the product p1=a'*b, rotate p1 about the Z-axis by 180 degrees to p2, what in practice is just flipping the signs of the i and j coefficients, and forming the scalar product of p1 and p2. The short version is

> scal(ka,kb) = p1.w*p1.w - p1.x*p1.x - p1.y*p1.y + p1.z*p1.z

Comment: Wow, that works perfectly. The problem is that I don't understand everythingy :). Seems like I still have a lot to learn. Anyway, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

1. Find 2 vectors dirA and dirB , the direction of camera and object. You can simply transform vector Z(0,0,1) by corresponding quaternions.
2. Find angle between vectors dirA dirB by

   angle = atan2( cross(dirA, dirB).len(), dot(dirS, dirB) )